Possibility to use access terminal to disarm the NVR
We have the NVR Hikvision with some cameras that send motion detection notification to Hik-Connect app.
I'm wondering whether it is possible to use Access control terminal (DS-K1T805MBFWX for example) to disarm the whole system before buying it.
Unfortunately, did not find clear information about this. A lot of manuals only tell how to use it to unlock the door, but i do not need it.

Yes it is possible.
On Access Terminal DS-K1T805MBFWX you set up server ip in Alarm Server or HTTP Listener, depending on firmware name vary.
Create a TCP server listener and fetch JSON / XML events from terminal.
Once you get to Invalid Card/PIN which should arm/disarm your system or standard authenticated event by userID and their card/pin(works same), then you push ISAPI request most likely PUT towards NVR to disble Notify Sureveilance center for motion detections.
You should keep track somewhere of the Arm/Disarm state yourself. Which can be done by using GET request towards property of NotifySurveillance checkmark.
Cheers
